# 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' when using MongoDB C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm running into a little bit of an issue while using MongoDB with C#. I am trying to get a collection of every document that belongs to a given collection. The collection should be made up of BsonDocuments and they all can be different.

I get a "System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException occurred in MongoDB.Bson" when I call the GetCollection function, as seen below.

```
    public List<BsonDocument> Get(string targetListName)
    {
        return _db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(targetListName).Find(new BsonDocument()).ToList();
    }
```

targetListName is the name of the collection that I want to return the BsonDocuments from.

Any idea why I would be getting this? I am guessing maybe it has something to do with the fact that some of the documents don't have values for certain keys, while others do... however I am pretty sure it was working before. If this is the case, is there a workaround?

Comment: I would guess it's your `Find(new BsonDocument())`.  `Find` usually throws if the item doesn't exist.  But I'm not familiar with that library.

Comment: what should I use instead? I am dealing with random collections that can have any number of keys/values.

Comment: Pretty sure you don't want the `Find` call at all.  Just take it out

Comment: @halterdev I know it's been a long time since you posted this question, but dit you find a solution for this issue?